# phpmyadmin shows weird code

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

after setting up apache and everything working correctly i tried to go to localhost/phpmyadmin and now instead of showing me the login page it's showing me this weird stuff: here is one line of it. it's a huge pile of code.

```
addJSON( 'list', PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) { PMA_printGitRevision(); exit; } echo '
```

and then below that php myadmin demo server with more pile of code..

Comment: Looks like apache php module is not installed. Try installing `libapache2-mod-php5` and reload/restart apache service

Comment: hey thanks for replying terminal says that libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate

Comment: also i have php7 idk if that helps

Comment: Can you provide some more details?. OS , PHP, Apache version. and the steps you followed to install apache, php and phpmyadmin. I will try to replicate the same in my local env

Comment: @aneeshep ubuntu 16.04. the steps were from digitalocean how to install LAMP.

Comment: okay. I am not sure which tutorial/guide you followed. there are many versions from Digital ocean itself. But the easy way to install LAMP will be apt group install. Try this command `apt-get install lamp-server^`. Don't forget the ^ symbol at the end. That tells apt-get that its a group install not a single package.

Comment: @aneeshep how can i do a fresh installation again? should i do the purge command to delete my LAMP?

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libapache2-mod-php` should fix it.

---

Then, you can purge your installation and, if you want a simple installer which rarely fails, use the script provided by apachefriends. https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: i have it installed bro.

Comment: @theprogrammer: According to your comments, you didn't have it installed initially when you wrote the question.

Comment: i checked it out after the first guy commeted. i tried again now and it said it's installed

Answer (score 0):

add this to apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        php_flag engine on
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```